# Problem with changing state when clicking on button

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a problem I can't deal with. In a project I'm working on, when I click on a colour, the colour of the t-shirt should change, but in the meantime I get an [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dPCVV.png). I really need help. Repo to project: https://github.com/ewaolczak/product-personalizer/commit/a70ad00e360bc96de28c32e27c9c8ee9b9626a6a?w=1

I have read the course material several times, searched for solutions on the Internet and still do not know where the error is.

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: [Error:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dPCVV.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please don't post links to github or external sites if possible, and instead, try and make your post self-contained (that way, the question can still be understood if the links die in the future). That means adding your code to your question as formatted text (see [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)). If you have a lot of code, try and make a small reproducible example of your issue (this should be something you do before asking a question as a debugging process) and post that. See [mre] for more info.

Answer (score 1):

On [line 25 of `OptionColor.js`](https://github.com/ewaolczak/product-personalizer/blob/a08a0b5dffe063dbdc77f7257136c2b54aa6ddd3/src/components/OptionColor/OptionColor.js#L25), you try accessing `setCurrentColor()` from props, which is likely where the error is thrown. This is because on [line 73 of `Product.js`](https://github.com/ewaolczak/product-personalizer/blob/a70ad00e360bc96de28c32e27c9c8ee9b9626a6a/src/components/Product/Product.js#L73), where the `<OptionColor>` component is used, you don't pass in a prop named "setCurrentColor" equal to a function.

To fix this, I think what you meant to do on line 73 of `Product.js` is:

```html
<OptionColor colors={props.colors} setCurrentColor={setCurrentColor} />
```

Answer (score 0):

In your file OptionColor.js you are calling `props.setCurrentColor(color)`. That function does not exist, because the parent has not got the prop defined.

In your Product.js file, add the following:

```
  <OptionColor
    colors={props.colors}
    setCurrentColor={setCurrentColor}
  />
```

Answer (score 0):

Why there is an error:

In your `OptionColor` component, the code describes that whenever the button is clicked, it will call `props.setCurrentColor(whatever-color)` like so:

```
<button onClick={() => props.setCurrentColor(color)}></button>
```

This is telling React to call the `setCurrentColor` argument passed into the component. The problem is, your `Product` component doesn't pass in a `setCurrentColor` function, just the `colors` array.

```
<OptionColor colors={props.colors} />
```

To fix:

Change the `OptionColor` usage in the `Product` component to:

```
<OptionColor colors={props.colors} setCurrentColor={setCurrentColor} />
```

To provide the `OptionColor` a way to change its parent's state.

Answer (score 0):

This is your [OptionColor.js](https://github.com/ewaolczak/product-personalizer/blob/master/src/components/OptionColor/OptionColor.js):

```js
import React from 'react';
import styles from './OptionColor.module.scss';
import shortid from 'shortid';
import clsx from 'clsx';

const OptionColor = (props) => {
  const prepareColorClassName = (color) => {
    return styles[
      'color' + color[0].toUpperCase() + color.substr(1).toLowerCase()
    ];
  };

  return (
    <div className={styles.colors}>
      <h3 className={styles.optionLabel}>Colors</h3>
      <ul className={styles.choices}>
        {props.colors?.map((color) => (
          <li key={shortid()}>
            <button
              type='button'
              className={clsx(
                prepareColorClassName(color),
                props.currentColor === color ? styles.active : undefined
              )}
              onClick={() => props.setCurrentColor(color)}></button>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}

export default OptionColor;
```

At the bottom in your `<li>` is this line, which is trying to call a `setCurrentColor`.  This function was was not passed to the component (it's undefined):

```js
onClick={() => props.setCurrentColor(color)}></button>
```

---

## Solution

In [Product.js](https://github.com/ewaolczak/product-personalizer/commit/a70ad00e360bc96de28c32e27c9c8ee9b9626a6a?w=1#diff-3f7043163607dd777caaf470721dd26b7a83656d7f7b86602b7fe37413a5232dR73), change:

```js
<OptionColor colors={props.colors} />
```

To:

```js
<OptionColor colors={props.colors} setCurrentColor={setCurrentColor} />
```